# The concept behind a shunt resistor

Tags: resistors

Why do we use "shunt resistors" and is there a difference between a standard resistor and a shunt? Or is this context based, e.g., as in pull-up or pull-down resistor?

Addition: What is meant by shunt? I'm sort of missing the fundamental concept as well.

Comment: Shunt resistor is a low-resistance (and high power in most cases) resistor put in series with a line one interested to measure the current on by measuring the voltage on the resistor.

Comment: *is there a difference between a standard resistor and a shunt* There is no difference, a shunt resistor is just a resistor. But often it has a low value to allow a large current to flow without too much voltage drop (burden voltage). More fancy shunt resistors can have additional connections to measure the voltage across the resistor more accurately (4 point measurement).

Comment: I know that shunt resistors can be used in parallel with an ammeter to allow larger currents to be measured and that means low resistance and high power rating;that's the proof for FakeMoustache's comment.

Comment: Also, shunts may be designed to have more accurate resistance values since they are used for measurement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that shunt resistors can be used in parallel with an ammeter to allow larger currents to be measured(larger than what is the ammeter rated for) and that's the proof for "low resistance and high power rating"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpWElo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Say that the ammeter depicted in the schematic can handle at most 10 A.Now Rshunt must have a smaller value than the ammeter's resistance.That's:

\$R_{shunt}=\frac{R_{ammeter}}{n-1}\$

Where n is the number of times I1 is bigger than the maximum AM1 current.

To shunt means to redirect  part of the current elsewhere which would otherwise flow through another path.

Answer (score 3):

The term "shunt" is strictly context-based.
However, shunt resistors most often have a very low resistance, because they are most often used to make current measurements. Such low resistances may have four terminals: two to make external circuit connections, and two for measurement:[image: Shunt resistor with four terminals] This shunt has two large terminals on top for external circuit connections, and two smaller screw terminals on the side for measurement. It may be connected to a specified amp meter (ammeter), or voltage can be measured from screw-terminal-to-screw-terminal. But its basic electrical property is the resistance of the flat metal bridge between the large terminal blocks.

Comment: Note that for measuring voltage it's called "additional resistor".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the name depends only on resistor's placement in circuit. A 10Ω shunt resistor can be used as 10Ω pull-up resistor if you need one. It would just probably be bigger than 10Ω resistor you'd use for a pull-up.

I personally like the medical definition of shunt (*an alternative path for the passage of the blood or other body fluid*) for explaining shunt resistor's purpose - it provides a path for high current to pass through without damaging other elements (often expensive equipment that does not like high currents flowing through them).