# add different current loads to test noise on DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, current-source

I want to test the LTM8021 DC-DC converter (using an eval board I bought - schematic for it is below) for noise output at varying current loads (10mA, 100mA, 200mA, 450mA) and still fairly new to this. My power supply can *limit* current but I can't tell it directly to just *supply* 10/100/200/450 mA. I figured I could add a series resistor using good 'ole Ohms law V=IR. I added it between the supply and VIN and GND and the supply GND and the supply and my multimeter never see it go above using 1mA. I know this is super simple but I can't seem to figure this out. what am I doing wrong? How would I go about injecting current loads?

[image: LTM8021EV board]

Comment: One programs current with a shunt resistor, not a series resistor.

Comment: from what I read on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278513/the-concept-behind-a-shunt-resistor/278529 it looks to just be terminology. What I'm asking for is how to implement. I'm not able to find any information in my searches and this kind of thing was never covered in any of my classes thus far. If it sounds better: I tried implementing a 100ohm resistor in pull-up and in pull-down and neither worked to increase the current on the circuit when I put a 10V power supply on it.

Comment: Current into E1 depends on a shunt resistance from E4 to E6.

Comment: @Whit3rd - so I would then use the (in this setup) 5V output instead of 10V input in ohms law equation to determine what resistor for desired current load, correct? would that affect the noise? (again I apologize for my greenness on this. I feel like my classes skipped a lot of this **useful practical stuff** and dove right into transistors for the last few years)

Comment: The most useful approximation here is that input V*I (input power) is roughly equal to output V*I.   The current load (output) is not the same as the current supply (input), so there's two different currents associated with the resistor on the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for anyone in the same situation: @Whit3rd (thanks for your help) was right about adding a resistor between Vout and GND. The output voltage (5V) determined the R value. With the Radj at that value it output roughly 5V so the tests I ran was at 10mA, 100mA, 200mA, and 450mA so I divided 5V by each of those to find the R value of the shunt resistor needed and it worked as expected after that.

The measurement was for noise so I followed the guide at https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/measuring_output_noise.pdf and attached my leads to both sides of the output cap for a more accurate reading.

Comment: That is an excellent treatment of the subject. Make sure you  follow EVERYTHING they say, especially the treatment of test probes.